# Was Up in the Air inspired by real world firms?

Tags: up-in-the-air

Are there firms in the real world that has staff who go to other companies to fire people like in the movie ***Up in the Air***? Did the movie take inspiration from a real world firm like the one George Clooney works for?

Answer (score 5):

[According to the Seattle PI](http://www.seattlepi.com/business/article/Do-hatchet-men-like-Clooney-s-Up-In-The-Air-893384.php):

> **The answer is not exactly**, although the film reflects trends in the
>   American workplace.
>
> As employment laws grow more numerous and complex, and workplace
>   litigation explodes, many firms are hiring outside consultants to help
>   them downsize. Some operate behind the scenes but their presence is
>   still felt; others participate directly in layoffs, but usually
>   alongside the employer.
>
> **More small and midsize employers are outsourcing their human resource
>   operations to outside firms**, sometimes called professional employer
>   organizations. These firms handle tasks such as payroll, workers'
>   compensation, benefits administration, and hiring and firing workers.
>
> **Laying off employees "is a service we provide,"** says Lisa Pinkard,
>   vice president of human resources with Emplicity, an HR outsourcing
>   firm in Irvine. "Usually we have long-term relationships with our
>   clients. It's not like we have mass layoffs and then leave."
>
> All of the firm's consultants will do layoffs as one of their many
>   jobs.

However:

> Rebecca Heyman says laying off workers "is a small part" of her job as
>   a senior human capital consultant with TriNet, an HR outsourcing firm
>   based in San Leandro.
>
> "My role is to be the out-of-house HR manager for these companies that
>   are our clients," she says. "If they are going through layoffs, I help
>   them manage that process. But I would not go in by myself and
>   terminate an employee without a representative of the company
>   delivering that message. I'll do a lot of coaching up front. I might
>   be in the room to be a witness/note taker and to answer operational
>   questions."
>
> Heyman thought "Up in the Air" "was a great character study on this
>   isolated individual. But **from an HR perspective, I didn't think it was
>   reality," she says.** "There is a lot of preparation that goes into
>   making the decision (to terminate someone). That would be too boring
>   to show in a movie. It's analysis, financial considerations. You're
>   not going to watch George Clooney work on a spreadsheet."
>
> Robert Conlon, a senior vice president with Sibson Consulting, agrees.
>   "To the extent it is portrayed in the movie, **I'm not aware of
>   companies that are hired to parachute in, deliver the message and
>   escape out of Dodge.**"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely there are. Although most external HR consultancies deal with hiring and firing [in conjunction with the company's own HR staff](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2010/01/getting_the_ax_from_george_clooney.html) there are some companies that offer this as a stand-alone services.

> **[The people who sack people](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/8524042.stm)**
>
> In the past 15 years, Janet Shearer has personally made thousands of
>   employees redundant.
>
> But Janet isn't some cold-hearted, cost-cutting chief executive. She's
>   the managing director of a British firm that sacks other companies'
>   employees.
>
> ...
>
> Ms Shearer says it's difficult to predict exactly how a person will
>   respond to being made redundant.
>
> She agrees that dignity and respect are key to handling the situation
>   - and it doesn't hurt to have some tissues at the ready.
>
> "It can be difficult, but you just try to see that you can support
>   them," she says. "It's not rich tea and sympathy and being really
>   fluffy… But if they wanted to grieve and let that out, absolutely."